PowerShell - Find strings in text file a also existing in text file b
I basically want to know if I have duplicates across 2 different text files. I managed to order the data for each text file into 1 column with multiple rows. So this would be the sample data:
File A
7456745
4523455
8566545
7685449
9875654

File B
7685449
9875654
2348921
1234932
4593023

Expected output:
7685449
9875654

Currently what I've been trying to do is:
get-content file A | select-string file B

But is returning nothing. I hope this is clear enough. Thanks in advance!


Use Compare-Object:
Compare-Object (Get-Content 'file A') (Get-Content 'file B') -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru


An efficient approach is to use Enumerable.Intersect:
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Intersect(
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('path\to\fileA.txt'),
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('path\to\fileB.txt'))

Note that when calling .NET methods that take a path as argument, it is important to pass-in the absolute path, alternatively if using relative paths you can use Convert-Path. See this Q&A for more info.
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Intersect(
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path 'fileA.txt')),
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path 'fileB.txt')))


Yet Another Way:
I know HashSets are high performance, so I like using them.  But I'm not sure where they compare to the previous answers.
This creates a HashSet based on $FileA, creates another HashSet based on $FileB, and finds where they intersect:
$FileA = "$PSScriptRoot\A.TXT"
$FileB = "$PSScriptRoot\B.TXT"
$DuplicateIDs = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([String[]](Get-Content $FileA))
$DuplicateIDs.IntersectWith([Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([String[]](Get-Content $FileB)))

This is essentially the same code as above, but simplified with HashSets of objects instead HashSets of strings:
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

$DuplicateIDs = [HashSet[Object]]::new((Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\A.TXT"))
$DuplicateIDs.IntersectWith([HashSet[Object]]::new((Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\B.TXT")))

And you can convert the $DuplicateIDs HashSet to an array of strings:
$Results = [string[]]$DuplicateIDs
$Results

